# Can't change rake version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rake, version

I am trying to downgrade my Rake version from 0.9.6 to 0.8.7.

This is because when I currently run `rake db:create` I get the `WARNING: 'require 'rake/rdoctask'' is deprecated.  Please use 'require 'rdoc/task' (in RDoc 2.4.2+)' instead.` error. (I also made sure that I have 'rdoc/task' in my Rakefile).

So I currently have 2 versions of rake installed (0.9.6 and 0.8.7), but only 0.9.6 is activated in my project folder.

So far I have tried to :

- `gem 'rake', '0.8.7'` but this gives me `unknown command rake,`
- `gem uninstall rake -v 0.9.6` but this gives me `gem "rake" cannot be uninstalled because it is a default gem`
- `gem uninstall rake` but this only removes the older version.
- `bundle install` with the 0.8.7 specified in my Gemfile, the output is ok, but when I run `rake --version` it still displays the 0.9.6 version.

Here's my Gemfile :

```
    source :rubygems
    gem 'rails','2.3.5'
    gem 'i18n','0.4.2'
    gem 'declarative_authorization','0.5.1'
    gem 'mysql','2.8.1'
    gem 'rake','0.8.7'
    gem 'rush','0.6.8'
    gem "iconv", "~> 1.0.3"
```

and my Gemfile.lock

```
GEM
  remote: http://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (2.3.5)
      actionpack (= 2.3.5)
    actionpack (2.3.5)
      activesupport (= 2.3.5)
      rack (~> 1.0.0)
    activerecord (2.3.5)
      activesupport (= 2.3.5)
    activeresource (2.3.5)
      activesupport (= 2.3.5)
    activesupport (2.3.5)
    declarative_authorization (0.5.1)
    i18n (0.4.2)
    iconv (1.0.4)
    mysql (2.8.1)
    rack (1.0.1)
    rails (2.3.5)
      actionmailer (= 2.3.5)
      actionpack (= 2.3.5)
      activerecord (= 2.3.5)
      activeresource (= 2.3.5)
      activesupport (= 2.3.5)
      rake (>= 0.8.3)
    rake (0.8.7)
    rush (0.6.8)
      session
    session (3.2.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  declarative_authorization (= 0.5.1)
  i18n (= 0.4.2)
  iconv (~> 1.0.3)
  mysql (= 2.8.1)
  rails (= 2.3.5)
  rake (= 0.8.7)
  rush (= 0.6.8)

BUNDLED WITH
   1.10.6
```

I tried to look everywhere, but nothing worked so far. Any hint ?

Thanks !

EDIT: Downgrading ruby from 2.0.0 to 1.8.7 has solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Prepend all your command in the project with `bundle exec ....`

Running a command with bundle exec at begin, launch a gem what installed with a `Gemfile` from the app directory, without `bundle exec` it is run gem what installed in to the system.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I run `bundle exec rake db:create` it will give me `rake aborted! `
Also what I'm looking for is to preferably not have to `bundle exec` rake.

Comment: @Lucbug this mean, you rake task success run but abourted. Here i show you the right way of using gem in project, no need to downgrande

Comment: you should use `bundle exec ...` in project(not in system), otherwise you can have version mismatch.